# Custom pivot model class does not exist in controller

Tags: laravel, pivot-table

I got a pivot table which holds extra data. So i created a custom pivot model like shown in the docs for Laravel 5.6.

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;

class PersonaTreeleave extends Pivot
{
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $table = 'persona_treeleave';

    protected $fillable = [
        'FK', 'RoleTitle', 'Merkmale'
    ];

    public function treeleave_id(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Treeleave');
    }

    public function persona_id(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Persona');
    }
}
```

In a controller file i want to attach a user to an already existing "treeleave".

```
App\Treeleave::where('cid',$P['OE'])
    ->where( 'tree', $Baum->id)->first()
    ->Persons()->attach($DBUser, [
        'FK' => $P['FK'],
        'RoleTitle' => $P['RoleTitle'],
        'Merkmale' => json_encode($P['Merkmale'])
    ]
);
```

I keep getting an error like "Class 'App\PersonaTreeleave' not found".

I dont get why that happens. It doesn't help if i add "Use App\PersonaTreeleave" in the controller file.

If i do this

```
dump(class_exists('App\Treeleave'));
dump(class_exists('App\PersonaTreeleave'));
```

it generates this output:

```
true

false
```

Anybody got a hint?

The classes for "treeleave" and "persona"

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Treeleave extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'treeleaves';
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $fillable = ['parent','lft','rgt','ebene','oe_titel','tree','meta'];

    public function Baum(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Tree');
    }
    public function Persons(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Persona')
        ->withPivot('FK', 'RoleTitle', 'Merkmale')
        ->using('App\PersonaTreeleave')
        ;
    }
}


namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Persona extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $attributes = [
        'titel' => ''
    ];
    protected $fillable = [
        'nachname', 'vorname', 'titel', 'projekt', 'email', 'geschlecht', 'cid'
    ];

    public function logins(){
        // erwartet Relations-Tabelle "login_project" (alphabetische Reihenfolge der beteiligten Tabellen, Namen im Singular)
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Login');
    }

    public function OE(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Treeleave')
        ->withPivot('FK', 'RoleTitle', 'Merkmale')
        ->using('App\PersonaTreeleave')
        ;
    }

    public function setTitelAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['titel'] = (string)$value;
    }
}
```

Comment: have u tried `composer dump-autoload`?

Comment: I tried to clear the artisan cache and so on....thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

To update your autoload file with the new class info.